# Retry of messages using Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to implement a retry of failed message delivery by consumer of Kafka. I followed the architecture explained [here](https://blog.pragmatists.com/retrying-consumer-architecture-in-the-apache-kafka-939ac4cb851a). Although it addresses the problem quite well, I am not convinced with the recommendation that we implement a wait/sleep in the application.

I may be comparing apple with oranges, but I am looking for an architecture similar to that provided by ActiveMQ's delayed and scheduled message feature.

Comment: you'll fry the cpu if you don't sleep. The recommendation is correct ; )

Answer (score 0):

One can use the KafkaConsumer.pause method instead of sleeping (keeps you in the group but stops recieving messages from poll()). You actually would not want to sleep for too long as the kafka consumer will fail to heartbeat and be kicked out of the group. You have to always call poll() to make the heartbeat mechanism continue.

Overall you could add sleeps but be wary that you will add delay to processing times and it would need to be less than the heartbeat timeout time to stay in the group. There is no other mechanism for being event driven as the kafka consumer is poll driven and not push based (with error handling falling on you).

You could leverage frameworks on top of the basic kafka consumer library to do this work for you however like:

- Kafka Streams
- Spring Kafka library

I would definitely opt to KISS and just do a tight retry loop or the pause method at most unless your app will spend 99% of its time retrying all the time (is that the case?). Are you designing to save CPU cycles or to actually achieve your functionality?

Highly suggest reading the whole javadoc for the KafkaConsumer as they have alot of different suggestions and use cases: https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the Kafka Retry project https://github.com/IBM/kafka-retry

Comment: what I am actually looking at is if the messages can be scheduled in kafka like activemq.. i guess that is against the design principle of kafka..

Comment: Kafka Retry allows you to send a message to a retry topic with the intention of it being produced back to the origin topic at some later time. Kafka Retry essentially stores the message until the wait time has elapsed and then sends it back. Disclaimer: I am the developer of Kafka Retry and it's still a nascent project, but happy to work on improvements due to feedback.